# How to combine two overlapping import statements into one

Tags: python

Can I write the following two lines of code in one?

```
from file import *
from file import foo as class_01
```

Comment: It is generally discouraged to use wildcard import. They make the tracing of names substantially harder.

Comment: `import file` should do the trick.

Comment: If you already imported everything, `class_01 = foo` will do what you are asking. But like everybody else here, I'll remind you that wildcard imports are a bad idea.

Comment: @barny it will do the trick (of being able to access everything under `file`) but will not give the same result...

Comment: Personally I always avoid the `from xyz import *` because it just makes a mess of the local namespace and makes it horribly easy to override something else causing at the best me having to rename local definitions or at worst very strange and sometimes difficult to diagnose errors.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but doing that imposes poorly readable code as it introduces unknown names to the interpreter.

Instead, consider importing all needed names

```py
from file import bar, foo as class_01
```

Comment: You’re supposed to give the answer too.

Comment: That doesn't work with `*` so I'm not sure it answers the question...

Comment: My answer is "Yes, you can, but you shouldn't".

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, but it is advisable to import specific class in a module
Example:

```
from shutil import make_archive as m_a,copy
```

Comment: That doesn't work with `*` so I'm not sure it answers the question...